# Eclipse not creating a Java project but instead only a Module

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently installed Java JDK 12.0.1 and set the **Environmental Variable** for **JAVA HOME** to

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\jdk-12.0.1

and added a new **Path Variable** and set it to

> C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\bin

I then installed Eclipse IDE for Java Developers from the Eclipse website and launched it. I proceeded to make a new Java Project and the end result was that it did not create a Java Project complete with a (default package) and .java file, etc. but rather it created a Module only.

I have pictures and will try to show them on here either as an attachment (if possible) or as links to images on uploaded on Imgur.

Any help is much appreciate.
Full disclosure: I am fairly new (might as well be) to coding and all this in general.

I've tried to uninstall both Eclipse and Java JDK multiple times but no luck.

No code to show currently but here are some images...

> Step 1

[image: Pic 1]

> Step 2

[image: Pic 2]

> Step 3

[image: Pic 3]

> Step 4a (if Create is selected)

[image: Pic 4]

> Step 4b (if Don't Create is selected)

[image: Pic 5]

> This is how it should be created (an older project I created a while back)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7n2L.jpg

Expected result: to create new Java projects.
Actual result: no new Java projects created.

**ERROR LOG**

```html
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2019-05-27 20:29:09.550
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrt.addRequired(ClasspathJrt.java:326)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrt.selectModules(ClasspathJrt.java:320)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.getModuleNames(ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.java:347)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.collectModuleEntries(NameEnvironment.java:397)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.computeClasspathLocations(NameEnvironment.java:319)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.<init>(NameEnvironment.java:62)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.initializeBuilder(JavaBuilder.java:629)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:174)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:833)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:371)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:392)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 75 2019-05-27 20:29:09.552
!MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 75 2019-05-27 20:29:09.552
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'ProjectA'.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrt.addRequired(ClasspathJrt.java:326)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrt.selectModules(ClasspathJrt.java:320)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.getModuleNames(ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.java:347)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.collectModuleEntries(NameEnvironment.java:397)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.computeClasspathLocations(NameEnvironment.java:319)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.<init>(NameEnvironment.java:62)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.initializeBuilder(JavaBuilder.java:629)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:174)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:833)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:371)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:392)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2019-05-27 20:29:10.025
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrt.addRequired(ClasspathJrt.java:326)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrt.selectModules(ClasspathJrt.java:320)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.getModuleNames(ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.java:347)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.collectModuleEntries(NameEnvironment.java:397)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.computeClasspathLocations(NameEnvironment.java:319)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.<init>(NameEnvironment.java:62)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.initializeBuilder(JavaBuilder.java:629)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:174)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:833)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:371)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:392)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 75 2019-05-27 20:29:10.027
!MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 75 2019-05-27 20:29:10.027
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'ProjectA'.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrt.addRequired(ClasspathJrt.java:326)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrt.selectModules(ClasspathJrt.java:320)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.getModuleNames(ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.java:347)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.collectModuleEntries(NameEnvironment.java:397)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.computeClasspathLocations(NameEnvironment.java:319)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.<init>(NameEnvironment.java:62)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.initializeBuilder(JavaBuilder.java:629)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:174)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:833)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:371)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:392)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
!SESSION 2019-05-27 22:07:25.989 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.11.0.I20190307-0500
java.version=12.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
```

**NEW ERROR LOG**

```html
~~~[THIS WAS WHEN I LAUNCHED IT VIA THE CMD PROMPT AS INSTRUCTED]~~~

!SESSION 2019-05-30 06:55:00.262 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.11.0.I20190307-0500
java.version=11.0.3
java.vendor=AdoptOpenJDK
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core 4 0 2019-05-30 06:55:01.002
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core [270]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.24.2.v20180904-2231"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc [287]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.0.0.v20100427-1100"
              org.apache.xmlrpc [57]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.xmlrpc
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.0.0.v20100427-1100"

 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:452)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1784)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1763)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1726)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1657)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:233)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:343)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ui 4 0 2019-05-30 06:55:01.005
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ui [272]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core; bundle-version="3.24.2.v20180905-0003"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core [270]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.24.2.v20180904-2231"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc [287]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.0.0.v20100427-1100"
                     org.apache.xmlrpc [57]
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.xmlrpc
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.0.0.v20100427-1100"

 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:452)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1784)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1763)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1726)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1657)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:233)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:343)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc 4 0 2019-05-30 06:55:01.006
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc [287]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.0.0.v20100427-1100"
       org.apache.xmlrpc [57]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind

 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:452)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1784)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1763)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1726)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1657)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:233)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:343)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.core 1 0 2019-05-30 06:55:02.279
!MESSAGE Using Apache MINA sshd as ssh client.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core 4 0 2019-05-30 06:55:03.573
!MESSAGE Unexpected error while loading repository template extensions
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core 4 0 2019-05-30 06:55:03.573
!MESSAGE Could not load repository template extension contributed by 'org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ide' with connectorKind 'bugzilla'

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2019-05-30 06:55:06.714
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\[REDACTED]'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

~~~[THIS WAS WHEN I ATTEMPTED TO CREATE A NEW JAVA PROJECT]~~~

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2019-05-30 07:03:07.492
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4699)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4614)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4585)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:451)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:350)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.getChildren(Composite.java:469)
 at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplaceDropAdapter.lambda$0(MarketplaceDropAdapter.java:136)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3919)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3550)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:566)
 at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:661)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1476)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1449)
```

Comment: I don't think it's ever created both a default package and a Java source file when you just create a project. That would be useless for anyone doing anything more than a simple "Hello, World" kind of application. Also, for the **New module-info.java** dialog, did you try the **Don't create** button?

Comment: Yes, I tried the **Don't Create** button which produces the 5th picture. Also, I will post a 6th picture to demonstrate an example of how I've seen it structured in the past when a new Java Project is created.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/1uivKUJ

This is how it should look and how past projects have been constructed.

Comment: Does the workspace's .metadata\.log file have a trace for that NullPointerException? Looks like a bug.

Comment: Good question. Where can I locate that to check and see?

Comment: I was able to find it and was able to see the entries in the log for NullPointerException. I posted the errors from the log into the question.

Comment: check compatibility with your OS like is your system 32 bit/64bit, respective eclipse and jdk

Comment: For Java 12 you have to install [Java 12 Support for Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11)](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-12-support-eclipse-2019-03-411). Alternatively, you can use Java 11 (with LTS in contrast to Java 12) or wait for Eclipse 2019-06.

Comment: @dkb - Yes, my Eclipse version, JDK version and OS are all 64 bit.

Comment: @howlger - I tried that and I got this error message - https://imgur.com/a/273PILy

Comment: @howlger - I downloaded the only JKD 11 I could find which did not require payment to Oracle, which was JDK 11.0.3.7-hotspot from AdoptOpenJDK. Unfortunately the same problem of Eclipse only creating a Module exists.

Comment: @onesAndZeros You have to add the JDK in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ and use it in the _New Java Project_ dialog (by choosing _JavaSE-11_ as _execution environment JRE_). The failed installation might be due a network issue or maybe you are behind a proxy.

Comment: @howlger - Like this? https://imgur.com/a/K7WlX1Z and this? https://imgur.com/a/2JEQo49

Comment: @howlger - Also this happened when I selected JavaSE-11 as the Execution Environment: https://imgur.com/a/yn6Ydzo and this https://imgur.com/a/LbAMOFF

Comment: @onesAndZeros This looks like [Eclipse bug 546338](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=546338). Unfortunately, it is not known how this issue can be reproduced. Could you please try to [run Eclipse with Java 11](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM)?

Comment: @howlger - Yes, and just to clarify what you mean, do you mean install the JDK 11 and use it within Eclipse as I am already? Or do you mean something else? I'm up to try almost anything to get Eclipse to function properly.

Comment: @onesAndZeros You have added Java 11 to _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ so you can use it in your Java project. But I mean run Eclipse with Java 11 instead of Java 12. You can do this on the command line with `eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.3.7-hotspot\bin\javaw.exe"`.

Comment: @howlger - I copy and pasted that exact command into Command Prompt and an elevated Command Prompt and this is what I got: https://imgur.com/a/keEjODj

Comment: @onesAndZeros You have to do a `cd "C:\Program Files\Java\java-2019-03\eclipse"` first. Did you use the Eclipse Installer or downloaded a ZIP to install Eclipse?

Comment: @howlger - I used the Eclipse Installer from the Eclipse website. Also, I tried it  again by doing that "cd" part first and it successfully loaded Eclipse but unfortunately it did not let me create a Java project and still is only creating a Module.

Comment: @onesAndZeros Do you get exactly the same `NullPointerException` when running Eclipse with the Java 11 OpenJDK and without having a Java 12 JDK/JRE in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_?

Comment: @howlger - Not this time. I added the new error log as a snippet onto the question at the bottom so you can see what it's doing as of currently.